# Understanding keycloak authentication with mozilla-django-oidc

Tags: django, keycloak, openid-connect

I am currently trying to use Keycloak with Django.
I use the mozilla-django-oidc package for this and have used [this tutorial](https://phasetwo.io/blog/secure-django/) as a guide, but with my own Keycloak server.

So far, everything is working fine. The protected view can only be accessed after logging in via Keycloak.

However, django rest framework is causing me problems.
I have made the configuration as described in the instructions, but I always get 401 (Unauthorized) back for requests to the Django Rest Framework endpoint.
And I don't understand why.

As far as I understand it, mozilla-django-oidc sets a "sessionid" cookie to authenticate the user.
I can also access the protected view.

For a request to the Django Rest Framework endpoint, however, I have to send an Authorization header with the access token according to the mozilla-django-oidc documentation.

But where do I get this access token in my single page application to set it in the Authorization header?

I have tried to read the access token in the SPA from the mentioned "sessionid" cookie. But this cookie is http only.

Comment: OIDC only takes care of authenticating using already obtained token (https://mozilla-django-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/stable/drf.html). To obtain token, you need to use Keycloak token endpoint. Refer to keycloak docs at https://www.keycloak.org/docs/24.0.1/authorization_services/#_service_overview

Comment: As already described, I used the tutorial as a guide.
If I am not authenticated, mozilla-django-oidc redirects me to the Keycloak login page.
I log in there and am then redirected back to my application.
How do I then obtain the token?
Do I have to request the access token myself after logging in and being redirected to my application? How do I do that? Because I don't have the user name and password from the user, as this was entered on the Keycloak login page.